# create new if already exists PHP

Tags: php, function, insert, pdo, user-registration

I am creating a random user ID, but I would like to check if the ID already has been used (very unlikely but the chances are there), but somehow this doesn't work. When I look in the database, there is no random character string in the `account_id` field. Do I call the functions in a wrong way?

```
function genRandomString() {
    $length = 40;
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";    
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}

function createID() {
    $cl_id = 'h_u_'.genRandomString();
}   

createID();

$sql_query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_id = :cl_id";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
$statement->bindParam(':cl_id', $cl_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
if ($statement->execute() && $row = $statement->fetch())
    {
        createID();
    }

$conn->exec("INSERT INTO accounts SET  
            account_id='$cl_id' ,
            name='$_POST[name]' ,
            email='$_POST[email]' ");
```

Comment: don't you have a Auto-Incrementing column? that would less the pain of checking if the ID exist? because auto-incrementing columns will just populate automatically your ID column by an incrementing number does make sure no rows is exactly the same

Comment: he could make an id column as a primary key and add his user_id as varchar(10) or something as an unique index ...

Comment: Having a Primary Key as a string is not very efficient, in many aspect. Plus, your code does not garantee that the column will be unique (assuming you also have this constraint set on that column). Why don't you have an AUTO_INCREMENT PK and, if you *really* need some unique identifier string, just generate one (sha1) from the user id (PK auto increment) and the email. Both should be unique in the first place anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$cl_id is a local variable in createID() function , you need to return your value to your global code ...

```
function createID() {
return $cl_id = 'h_u_'.genRandomString();
}
```

you need to check $id in the main code

```
$id = createID();
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_id = '".$cl_id."'";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of binding params then?

Comment: no problem, please take into account feedback from other users in case it could improve your project or app ... have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

1 . You missed to return $c_id in createID(). Change it to:

```
function createID() {
    return 'h_u_'.genRandomString();
}

$cl_id = createID();
```

2 . You could use good old `uniqid()` instead of your custom `genRandomString()`.

This would lead to something simpler like:

```
function createID() {
    return 'h_u_'.uniqid();
}

$cl_id = createID();
```

3 . You'll have to change the if in the database related code to a loop (have a look at my example below)

4 . Your insert query uses unverified $_POST vars. This is highly prone to [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). If your Database library supports **server side** prepared statements you should **use** them and you can feel secure because data is being kept separate from the query syntax. If you are using PHP with MySQL this is the case.

If you are not using **server side** prepared statements you should escape any $_POST data used in the query by using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or something like this. In the following example I'm assuming that you are using PHP with MySQL and thatswhy I use a prepared statement.

Taking all this in account may result in a finished script like this:

```
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_id = :cl_id";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
$maxtries = 3; // how many tries to generate a unique id?

for($i = 0; $i < $maxtries; $i++) {
    $cl_id = uniqid(); // create a 'unique' id

    $statement->bindParam(':cl_id', $cl_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        die('db error');
    }

    $row = $statement->fetch();
    if($row) {
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

// if a unique id couldn't get generated even
// after maxtries, then pigs can fly too :)
if($i === $maxtries) {
    die('maximum number of tries reached. pigs can fly!');
}

// You should use a prepared statement for the insert to prevent from
// SQL injections as you pass $_POST vars to the query. You should further 
// consider to validate email address and the name!
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$insert_query = '
  INSERT INTO accounts SET 
    account_id = :account_id,
    name = :name,
    email = :email'; 

$insert_statement = $conn->prepare($insert_query);
$insert_statement->bindParam(':account_id', $cl_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_statement->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_statement->bindParam(':account_id', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if (!$insert_statement->execute()) {
    die('db error');
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but please don't show interpolating $_POST variables directly into SQL.  Someone might use your code thinking it's correct, but it's a wide open SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Bill Karwin .. Yes, you are right. Most of the PHP/MySQL related posts are prone for multiple vulnerabilities. But what should I do? Writing examples full of security checks so that the ( assumed unexperienced ) questioner wouldn't understand the principals of the answer anymore? Again and again? I'm not sure.. Suggestions welcome! ....

Comment: Yeah, it's a good point, if we were to follow all coding best practices we would track the code in source control and write unit tests.  :-)  But I think replacing string interpolation with SQL query parameters is a reasonable compromise.  BTW, it's easier to pass the values as an array argument to `execute()` instead of writing all those `bindParam()` calls.  PDO just ignores the PARAM types anyway, at least in the MySQL driver.

Comment: Ok, will prepare some snippets for this ;)